# Observer are not called on create()

Tags: ember.js

I have a `Ember.Mixin` which observes one of its properties (here `bar.baz`).

I've extended this Mixin and set `bar.baz` in the `.create()` parameter, but my observer is not called.

Here is my code :

```
App.FooMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    barBazDidChange: function() {
        console.log('barBazDidChange'); // never called
    }.observes("bar.baz")
});

App.Foo = Ember.Object.extend(App.FooMixin);

App.fooObject = App.Foo.create({
    bar: Ember.Object.create({
        baz: "ember"
    })
});​
```

And the associated jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aMQmn/

I could of course call the observer in the `init()` method like below, but I wonder if there is a better solution (or if this solution is the proper way to do that) :

```
App.FooMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    init: function() {
      this._super();
      if (this.getPath('bar.baz')) { 
        this.notifyPropertyChange('bar.baz');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not specific to the fact you're nesting the attribute. The attribute 'bar.baz' doesn't change, it is always it's original value. 
Is it a more complex situation in your actual code?

Comment: even if you observe only 'bar', the observer isn't notified at creation time. I was a little bit suprised by this behavior...

Comment: yep I know that, I just wanted to be more closer to my goal, sorry. And no the situation in my code is not really more complex, but there are a lot of different observers.

Comment: I think Yehuda Katz have posted an answer which can be related to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420357/why-dont-the-arguments-to-create-behave-more-like-setproperties

Comment: An issue has been opened, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1205#issuecomment-7190161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So no answer during 7days... what I would do instead of passing the property at creation time is chaining the creation and setting the property, like this:

```
App.fooObject = App.Foo.create().set('bar', Ember.Object.create({baz: "ember"}));​
```

If it's not satisfying enough, perhaps you could post an issue in the ember project on github:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues

Comment: I really don't like this solution because I'm writing an Ember library, and I don't want to force the user to use a specific behavior when using this library. The Yehuda Katz answer looks very interesting, and I'll wait some days to see what will be decided. Thanks anyway

Comment: @louiscoquio You probably saw I've pointed your question there. I Hope Yehuda will have the time to answer. Just out of curiosity, is your library hosted on a public github repo or somewhere else ?

Comment: I don't find an other way to contact you ^^. I just realized your french guy too, it would be simpler to discuss in french. I've taken a look at your project. We are currently on the way of doing some client-side validation now. I think we would try to use ember-validations to do this. Did you ever communicate to the ember-team if they plan to include it into ember.js core ? Anyway, can we use it in our ember-data based models ?

Comment: The development has just started, so you'll have to wait before using it. I did not inform the core team about this library; I'll do it soon, but I want to wait for having a more "consistent" library to introduce

Comment: Ok, no problem. Anyway, we can't use it, since there is already a property errors defined in DS.Model. But I think the way you declare validations is really good, and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is to override the `init` method (make sure to call `this._super()`) and call the function there. As others have noted, the observer is not firing because the value is not actually changing. There has been some discussion around making `create` behave more like `setProperties` which would make this a non-issue.